# Rotated barChart in a Billboard.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, bar-chart, billboard.js

I use billboard.JS to display a rotated BarChart. But I'm trying to get category values on the y-axis, using this code

```
var data = [
  ["data11", 30],
  ["data2", 130],
  ["data3", 130]
];

// Generate the chart
var chart = bb.generate({
  data: {
    columns: data,
    type: "bar"
  },
  axis: {
    rotated: true, // Rotate the axis
    x: {
      type: "category", // Use the first column as categories
      categories: ["data11", "data2", "data3"]
    },
    y: {
      label: "Value" // Add a label for the y-axis
    }
  },
  bindto: "#barChart_1" // Bind the chart to a div element with id 'chart'
});
```

The result am Getting is this
[image: the current result]

but i want to get something like this instead

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var chart = bb.generate({
  data: {
    columns:  [ 
      ["data11", 30],
      ["data2", null, 130],
      ["data3", null, null, 130],
    ],
    type: "bar",
    groups: [["data11", "data2", "data3"]]
  },
  axis: {
    rotated: true, 
    x: {
      type: "category",
            categories: [
                "data11",
                "data2",
                "data3",
        ],
    },
    y: {
      label: "Value"
    }
  },
  bindto: "#barChart_1"
});
```

```html
<!-- Step 1) Load D3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>

<!-- Step 2) Load billboard.js with style -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/billboard.js/3.10.3/billboard.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load with base style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/billboard.js/3.10.3/billboard.min.css">

<div id="chart"></div>
```

See this Link for further help:
https://github.com/naver/billboard.js/issues/789